# Gmail API - Getting different results with users.threads.list vs users.messages.list

Tags: javascript, gmail-api

I am getting the matching Gmail primary inbox with messages.list however threads.list is missing some. Is this expected behaviour or a bug? Below you can see that thread 177c7390dbe418f6 is missing.

```
//Node
const { google } = require('googleapis');
....
gmail.users.messages.list({ userId: 'me', q: "category:primary" }
```

```
"messages": [
      {
        "id": "177d95c243426586",
        "threadId": "177c7390dbe418f6" //<-- missing
      },
      {
        "id": "177d916083ea15f2",
        "threadId": "177d916083ea15f2"
      },
      {
        "id": "177d8e899d5f4182",
        "threadId": "177d8e899d5f4182"
      },
      {
        "id": "177d8a7f03de3e21",
        "threadId": "177d8a7f03de3e21"
      },
      {
        "id": "177d87e44979a7ae",
        "threadId": "176d6316f79dafac"
      }
    ],
```

```
//messages with threads included
[
    [
      {
        "id": "177c7390dbe418f6",
        "threadId": "177c7390dbe418f6", //<--Missing
        "labelIds": [
          "SENT"
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "177cb7de28523956",
        "threadId": "177c7390dbe418f6", //<--Missing
        "labelIds": [
          "IMPORTANT",
          "CATEGORY_PERSONAL",
          "INBOX"
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "177d95c243426586",
        "threadId": "177c7390dbe418f6", //<-- Missing
        "labelIds": [
          "UNREAD",
          "IMPORTANT",
          "CATEGORY_PERSONAL",
          "INBOX"
        ]
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "id": "177d916083ea15f2",
        "threadId": "177d916083ea15f2",
        "labelIds": [
          "UNREAD",
          "IMPORTANT",
          "CATEGORY_PERSONAL",
          "INBOX"
        ]
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "id": "177d8e899d5f4182",
        "threadId": "177d8e899d5f4182",
        "labelIds": [
          "UNREAD",
          "IMPORTANT",
          "CATEGORY_PERSONAL",
          "INBOX"
        ]
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "id": "177d8a7f03de3e21",
        "threadId": "177d8a7f03de3e21",
        "labelIds": [
          "UNREAD",
          "IMPORTANT",
          "CATEGORY_PERSONAL",
          "INBOX"
        ]
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "id": "176d6316f79dafac",
        "threadId": "176d6316f79dafac",
        "labelIds": [
          "SENT"
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "177d87e44979a7ae",
        "threadId": "176d6316f79dafac",
        "labelIds": [
          "UNREAD",
          "IMPORTANT",
          "CATEGORY_PERSONAL",
          "INBOX"
        ]
      }
    ]
  ]
```

VS

```
gmail.users.threads.list({ userId: 'me', q: "category:primary" }
```

```
"threads": [
      {
        "id": "177d916083ea15f2",
        "historyId": "8030491"
      },
      {
        "id": "177d8e899d5f4182",
        "historyId": "8030418"
      },
      {
        "id": "177d8a7f03de3e21",
        "historyId": "8030344"
      },
      {
        "id": "176d6316f79dafac",
        "historyId": "8030240"
      },
      {
        "id": "177d8504c8c8b1f3",
        "historyId": "8030163"
      }
    ],
```

```
//Threads with threads included
[
    [
      {
        "id": "177d916083ea15f2",
        "threadId": "177d916083ea15f2",
        "labelIds": [
          "UNREAD",
          "IMPORTANT",
          "CATEGORY_PERSONAL",
          "INBOX"
        ]
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "id": "177d8e899d5f4182",
        "threadId": "177d8e899d5f4182",
        "labelIds": [
          "UNREAD",
          "IMPORTANT",
          "CATEGORY_PERSONAL",
          "INBOX"
        ]
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "id": "177d8a7f03de3e21",
        "threadId": "177d8a7f03de3e21",
        "labelIds": [
          "UNREAD",
          "IMPORTANT",
          "CATEGORY_PERSONAL",
          "INBOX"
        ]
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "id": "176d6316f79dafac",
        "threadId": "176d6316f79dafac",
        "labelIds": [
          "SENT"
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "177d87e44979a7ae",
        "threadId": "176d6316f79dafac",
        "labelIds": [
          "UNREAD",
          "IMPORTANT",
          "CATEGORY_PERSONAL",
          "INBOX"
        ]
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "id": "177d8504c8c8b1f3",
        "threadId": "177d8504c8c8b1f3",
        "labelIds": [
          "UNREAD",
          "IMPORTANT",
          "CATEGORY_PERSONAL",
          "INBOX"
        ]
      }
    ]
  ]
```

And the gmail screenshot:
[image: Gmail Image]

And the message in question:

```
 {
    "id": "177d95c243426586",
    "threadId": "177c7390dbe418f6",
    "labelIds": [
      "UNREAD",
      "IMPORTANT",
      "CATEGORY_PERSONAL",
      "INBOX"
    ],
    "snippet": "...",
    "historyId": "8030637",
    "internalDate": 1614259426000,
    "headers": {
      "delivered-to": "abbe...",
      "received": "from ...     by smtp.gmail.com with ESMTPSA id ...       for ...   (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);        Thu, 25 Feb 2021 05:23:49 -0800 (PST)",
      "x-received": "by 2002:a63:574c:: with SMTP id h12mr2977961pgm.79.1614259429959;        Thu, 25 Feb 2021 05:23:49 -0800 (PST)",
      "arc-seal": "...",
      "arc-message-signature": "...",
      "arc-authentication-results": "i=1; mx.google.com;       dkim=pass header.i=@gmail.com header.s=20161025 header.b=j4XrBr4D;       spf=pass (google.com: domain of askho56@gmail.com designates 209.85.220.41 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=askho56@gmail.com;       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=gmail.com",
      "return-path": "<...@gmail.com>",
      "received-spf": "pass (google.com: domain of ...@gmail.com designates 209.85.220.41 as permitted sender) client-ip=...;",
      "authentication-results": "mx.google.com;       dkim=pass header.i=@gmail.com header.s=20161025 header.b=j4XrBr4D;       spf=pass (google.com: domain of ...@gmail.com designates 209.85.220.41 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=askho56@gmail.com;       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=gmail.com",
      "dkim-signature": "v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;        d=gmail.com; s=20161025;        h=from:to:references:in-reply-to:subject:date:message-id:mime-version         :thread-index:content-language;        bh=9RIVZJQIdQ145qicwqQ7iKS3TwjG9ZDheghiZUXFXuI=;        b=j4XrBr4DxweFoikxZY8lZyealxFGXhiIU5pKqiPlomhBkBCXnI7N92ApKKVm/Skf2r         pAMmfUx7DmPJVQXTTIUfZd1gR13tz2DavTeD9AjpORQaY0NUGzPzp4sGKGFj0NTTLrAR         +3wfY1xLUHmNuQ8Z+PL6c5flVYt2KS3LvvliKgAnmnFVYRLllvs4satCuDtQhP+HgALz         QMZPgCZUq99snfuJXTZC9SkdF8l6vKJAd+zq6JYo5yZPxlII/MES0Xb6O3b61m5zWW11         extjaQd5B8tqof0KzDwk17qBHHc1P5mc5MYmDNyLaJMqcdgZaatyuQUuUHQJbjt2/CDo         F2sw==",
      "x-google-dkim-signature": "v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;        d=1e100.net; s=20161025;        h=x-gm-message-state:from:to:references:in-reply-to:subject:date         :message-id:mime-version:thread-index:content-language;        bh=9RIVZJQIdQ145qicwqQ7iKS3TwjG9ZDheghiZUXFXuI=;        b=bM7BL8AaIFGZ3ft3UUaVWwKb/OkzftkB1fn11PjGCeDjX9/Qts2hV5YUzxvWDmExth         1wDTDWuY3jsckatmaFOHIi68KNs4miI3ar3pkkUWWaVat3CMBS3D0d45nynw4R9yJ1UY         Za9oyVZVlx2dKjvmlrGq1GfrAubE7oBILnNSesXw4ktkGVGtt4wBRDOUS2Lp7GtIacBo         AkhWOj66h6D8Z3pDQksYkKmR6icEodEZqF+GnGRRSKIlOXTJgJ+ZOSD8WlxTXqfquDLZ         zam5t2Jfw1LDh38iEYGNwmTRgS/8OGD/IIchqeaRAzI8dDSacWyDD68B8ZM/+CYZeq5K         8Lqg==",
      "x-gm-message-state": "AOAM5315vcQLZN2q6mzYzD1h/Q+VjgxfftKW/9of/zsMG+2gAD9JT+KQ NwwwUxxzIFTcNdvQP73IJcfoL4ykZfA=",
      "x-google-smtp-source": "ABdhPJxvsCGrYU2YwKb/RmhkcFeGuQ8euddnu7MMVdfBfKNmVyRg8SoqEAsOFJBJz6B84Hri6GGD8A==",
      "from": "arthur ...<...@gmail.com>",
      "to": "\"'...'\" <...@gmail.com>",
      "references": "<887dff91ea6722640b52d2bc0ada71f9@10.0.0.7>",
      "in-reply-to": "<887dff91ea6722640b52d2bc0ada71f9@10.0.0.7>",
      "subject": "RE: ...",
      "date": "Thu, 25 Feb 2021 23:23:46 +1000",
      "message-id": "<000001d70b79$73f4cb50$5bde61f0$@gmail.com>",
      "mime-version": "1.0",
      "content-type": "multipart/alternative; boundary=\"----=_NextPart_000_0001_01D70BCD.45A28900\"",
      "x-mailer": "Microsoft Outlook 14.0",
      "thread-index": "AQL0hDxR4rpHIlSy+HdzbUnuCjMJK6gt5/1A",
      "content-language": "en-au"
    },
```

Comment: I suppose you have 5 messages in your account and so 5 threads. Can you confirm how many messages are related to message **177d140fe6d83af2**? In other words can you share a sanitized screenshot of this message? Probably this message has a thread associated but this is not a "conversation" yet.

Comment: @JoseVasquez Ive updated my question to include more info. My inbox get about 20 emails a day but the error happens all the time. Currently the top message isn't showing up in threads.

Comment: As I can see in the response you created the thread `177c7390dbe418f6`. Perhaps Google's automated attempt to categorize your incoming email has for some reason removed the first message (threadId `177c7390dbe418f6`) from **Primary** category. Can you please make a request to `users.threads.list` endpoint without the query **category:primary** and look if the threads with id `177c7390dbe418f6` appears?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like ***users.threads.list*** are sorted by the **first** messages date and ***users.messages.list*** are sorted by the **last** messages date. So the thread is in the list however it would be way down the line.  Not sure if the API guys intended it that way.

Here is an example below:

```
"threads": [
    [
      {
        "id": "1780f8decc0b5a58",
        "threadId": "1780f8decc0b5a58",
        "au_date": "3/8/2021, 11:57:35 AM"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "id": "1780f58cb4c7675e",
        "threadId": "1780f58cb4c7675e",
        "au_date": "3/8/2021, 10:58:57 AM"
      },
      {
        "id": "1780f5e7f6a06cba",
        "threadId": "1780f58cb4c7675e",
        "au_date": "3/8/2021, 11:05:54 AM"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "id": "1780f3c8a5126706",
        "threadId": "1780f3c8a5126706",
        "au_date": "3/8/2021, 10:28:40 AM"
      },
      {
        "id": "1780f55af3e43cb9",
        "threadId": "1780f3c8a5126706",
        "au_date": "3/8/2021, 10:56:16 AM"
      },
      {
        "id": "1780f9ee29256bac",
        "threadId": "1780f3c8a5126706",
        "au_date": "3/8/2021, 12:16:12 PM" <--this is the latest message however it is down the line a bit.
      }
    ],
]
```